# For loop in pairwise correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have tried to learn about loops and functions in R. So I set myself to the following situation: I have a pairwise correlation matrix:

```
dados<-matrix(rnorm(100),5,5)
colnames(dados)<-c('A','B','C','D','E')
rownames(dados)<-c('A','B','C','D','E')
dados
cor<-cor(dados)
```

I want use loop and if conditions for retain combinations of variables that have values > 0.5 of my cor object. However, I can't find a way to relize a pairwise camparisson in the rows and columns of my matrix.

I have tried the following code:

** The # are the situation that I cant resolve...

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cor)){
 for (j in 1:ncol(cor)){

    # Here I think that I need args for compare each row with each column of my cor matrix, but I can't find these lines!

   if (cor[i,j]>0.5){

    # Here I think that need a new matrix with 3 columns for combine variables of row (A to E), column(A to E) and values (> 0.5). I' cant find these lines too!
    }
  }
}
```

Somebody help me to think about a way to solve this question?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why can't you just use `cor(dados) > .5` without the loop part? also, it's better not to name you correlation matrix `cor` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obvious don't need a loop:

```
set.seed(12)
dados           <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5, 5)
colnames(dados) <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
r               <- cor(dados)
```

you can use `which` to index the elements in the correlation matrix that are bigger than .5

```
inds   <- which(r > .5, arr.ind = TRUE) # arr.ind = TRUE will return you a matrix of indices
r2     <- r[inds]
rows   <- rownames(r)[inds[, 1]]
cols   <- colnames(r)[inds[, 2]]
result <- cbind(rows, cols, r2)
```